# Disable/Enable GUI Elements in AHK

Tags: windows, user-interface, autohotkey

```
Gui, Add, Radio, vVar, Sample Text!
Gui, Add, Button, gToggle vEnable, Toggle 
Gui, Show
Return 

Toggle:
GuiControl, Disable, Var
Return
```

This code creates a Radio and the "Toggle" function disables it. I keep seeing this technique being used to disable/grey-out elements, but I want something that toggles it on and off, but I'm not sure how to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Thought about it for a bit, came up with this:

```
isEnabled := True

Gui, Add, Radio, vVar, Sample Text!
Gui, Add, Button, gToggle vEnable, Toggle 
Gui, Show
Return 

Toggle:
isEnabled := !isEnabled

if isEnabled
    GuiControl, Enable, Var
if !isEnabled
    GuiControl, Disable, Var

Return
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Gui, Add, Radio, vVar, Sample Text!
Gui, Add, Button, gToggle vEnable, Toggle
Gui, Show
Return

Toggle:
    GuiControlGet, enabledState, Enabled, Var
    enabledState := !enabledState
    GuiControl, Enable%enabledState%, Var
Return
```

With this version you don't need to track the enabled state.